# i want to show the phonenum of the user if it is already entered then the it will show the phonenum

Tags: laravel

hi i am trying to show the phone num of the user if it is already entered then the num will show in the input field

```
<input type="tel" name="phonenum" id="phonenum" @if(isset($user))

{{$user->Phonenum}}

@endif>
```

i am trying to show it in this manner it is  not working any suggestion ??
how can i show the number of the user if it has already been entered by the user .
here in the user table

```
$table->integer('Phonenum')->nullable();
```

the field is set in this manner .any suggestion??

Comment: Trying setting {{$user->Phonenum}} in **value attribute** of input filed

Comment: Post your controller code